# Power BI - Calculate customer running overdue balance

Tags: powerbi, mdx, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate a running customer Overdue balance (not a running customer balance, which I already have). I want to see what the customer overdue balance is over time, not neccessarly today. I want to see how much was overdue for each customer last month, 2 months ago, 3 months ago, etc

Example data is:

Cust_Transactions

```
Account Amount  Created     Due         Closed
100000  226.67  01/09/2018  01/10/2018  15/12/2018
100000  125.00  11/11/2018  11/12/2018  18/02/2019
100000  550.35  01/01/2019  01/02/2019  15/05/2019
100000  250.55  09/03/2019  09/04/2019  19/05/2019
100000  655.00  05/04/2019  05/06/2019
```

What I need to calculate is:

```
DateTable.Date  Overdue
31/01/2019      125.00
28/02/2019      550.35
31/03/2019      550.35
30/04/2019      800.90
31/05/2019      0.00
30/06/2019      655.00
31/07/2019      655.00
31/08/2019      655.00
30/09/2019      655.00
31/10/2019      655.00
30/11/2019      655.00
31/12/2019      655.00
```

So at any given Datetable.Date, I need to see what the Overdue balance is for all customers/ a particular filtered customer customer. A transaction is overdue if:

Datetable.Date is greater than Due date, and less than Close date

Or

Datetable.Date is greater than Due date, and Close date is blank

Can anyone please hep with this? Its been bugging me for ages

Many thanks for all help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Overdue = 
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( DateTable[Date] )
RETURN SUMX (
    Cust_Transactions,
    IF (
        (Cust_Transactions[Due] < MaxDate && Cust_Transactions[Closed] > MaxDate)
        || (Cust_Transactions[Due] < MaxDate && ISBLANK ( Cust_Transactions[Closed] ) ),
        Cust_Transactions[Amount]
    )
)
```

Comment: This returns an error:
The syntax for '[Date]' is incorrect

Comment: What are the actual table and column names in your dataset where the Date dimension values exist? You need to replace the table and column names with the real ones.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on a different forum:

```
CALCULATE(sumx(FILTER(Cust_Transactions[Due]<=max(DateTable[Date]) 
&& (isblank(Cust_Transactions[Closed]) || 
Cust_Transactions[Closed]>max(DateTable[Date]))),Cust_Transactions[Amount]))+0
```

That does the trick